# Javascript office add in: getAsync() not working

Tags: javascript, office-js

I new to this so sorry if it's a stupid question.
I am trying out some things with creating an office add in.

What I want it to do is get the start time of a meeting you are composing and putting that in a HTML div.
Here is my .js:

```
 Office.onReady().then(function() {
    var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    getStartTime();
});

function getStartTime() {
  var timeText = document.getElementById("time");
  timeText.innerHTML = item.start.getAsync();
}
```

If I change "item.start.getAsync()" to a string everything works as expected.
If I change it to "item.start" the div becomes "undefined"
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Am I even trying to do this the right way?
Thanks

Comment: as the name suggests `getAsync` is asynchronous, meaning it does not return anything directly, it accepts a callback function that receives whatever you are trying to get as an argument

Comment: @PatrickHund I tried making a write function for this but it does not seem to work. Can you provide an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As @PatrickHund mention in the comment `getAsync` has asynchronous nature and you need to work with the result of the function on callback. The full example of how to [Get or set the time when composing an appointment in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-or-set-the-time-of-an-appointment#get-the-start-or-end-time) available through the link. You code may looks like ...

```
function getStartTime() {
    item.start.getAsync(
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
            write(asyncResult.error.message);
        }
        else {
            // Successfully got the start time, display it, first in UTC and 
            // then convert the Date object to local time and display that.
            write ('The start time in UTC is: ' + asyncResult.value.toString());
            write ('The start time in local time is: ' + asyncResult.value.toLocaleString());
        }
    });
}

// Write to a div with id='message' on the page.
function write(message){
    document.getElementById('time').innerText += message; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still does not get the time. The write function works so the problem is definitely with the getStartTime()

Comment: @SJ_WTF The statement "still doesn't work" doesn't help at all. You would need to debug the code and find out what `asyncResult` returns or what exception thrown. Please take a time to go over the resource article I pointed to as well, may be you are missing something. Your item has to be an appointment that the user is composing.

Comment: I did read your article and I'm pretty sure I did everything the way it tells you. The problem with debugging this is that I do not get any useful information out of it. I'm using the syswow64 F12 tool and there is no error or exception anywhere.

Comment: To clarify I'm using the "AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface" extension point element.

Comment: Sorry for the many comments, but I did some further testing.
When I copy and paste everything from my .js file to the developer console and run it from there everything works as expected...
Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @SJ_WTF SO is not the forum type of resource, but more like simple QandA. I believe you should have the answer on your original question, why your code didn't work. If you have further questions, you should post another one, somebody would try to address it. It looks like you have the problem now not with your code, but with tools you are using to develop your solution. For many questions the answer would be "debug". Why would you try VSCode?  Sorry, but for your original question I have nothing to add. Best regards.